# How Can I Compute The Automorphism Group of a Matroid?

Tags: list-manipulation, group-theory

I want to compute the automorphism group of a matroid. This reduces to the following (more general) problem:

Suppose I have a list of sets $\{\{b_{11},\dots,b_{1k}\},\dots,\{b_{k1},\dots,b_{kk}\}\}$ where each $b_{ij}$ is in $\{1,\dots,n\}$. The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on this set by: $$\begin{align}&s\cdot\{\{b_{11},\dots,b_{1k}\},\dots,\{b_{k1},\dots,b_{kk}\}\} \\ &=  \{\{sb_{11},\dots,sb_{1k}\},\dots,\{sb_{k1},\dots,sb_{kk}\}\}\end{align}$$

I want to find those elements of the symmetric group on $n$ elements that stabilize the entire set $\{\{b_{11},\dots,b_{1k}\},\dots,\{b_{k1},\dots,b_{kk}\}\}$.

The command `GroupSetwiseStabilizer` seems relevant but doesn't quite do what I want.

Comment: I think this does it by brute force. Not sure if there is a better way:

Comment: By the way, are these bona fide sets (orderless), or are they Mathematica lists (where order matters)? Just checking, since it says "list of sets"!

Comment: (I prettified the post (as is usual practice—hope that's ok) using latex, but if they're Mathematica lists, I'd go for either tuples in latex, or code fences instead!)

Comment: These are just orderless sets, thanks for the clarification! And thanks for fixing the post :)

Answer (score 6):

I think this does it by brute force. Not sure if there is a better way:

```
matroidauts[M_] := Module[{n, symgp, i, goodguys, M2},
n = Max[Flatten[M]];
symgp = GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[n]];
goodguys = {};
M2 = Sort[Sort /@ M];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[symgp], i = i + 1,
If[M2 == Sort[Sort /@ PermutationReplace[M2, symgp[[i]]]], 
AppendTo[goodguys, symgp[[i]]]]
 ];
PermutationGroup[goodguys]
]
```

Here are two examples (I also edited the code a bit to accommodate lists that don't come in a nice order to start).

Uniform matroid (2,4) -- the bases are all subsets of {1,2,3,4} of size 2:

```
basesu24 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}};
```

And, it's automorphism group is the symmetric group on 4 elements:

```
Length[GroupElements[matroidauts[basesu24]]]
24
```

Fano matroid -- it is equivalent to work with the non-bases, which are listed below:

```
nonbasesFANO = {{7, 1, 4}, {7, 2, 5}, {7, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 
4}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5}};
```

It's automorphism group is PSL(2,7) which has order 168:

```
Length[GroupElements[matroidauts[nonbasesFANO]]]
168
```

Comment: A working algorithm is always a good thing for testing purposes. Would you please also provide a test data set?

Comment: Note: you don't need `Return` at the end of the function! `Return` is used to exit control structures like `;` prematurely. When something comes at the end of the evaluation, you can simply leave it as is, and the function will evaluate to that.

Comment: I've updated to include 2 examples! Thanks for the tip about Return-- I've been using Mathematica for about 10 years and I'm still shocked at the "basic" things I don't know!

Comment: Slightly change code to avoid `For`, `matroidauts[M_]:=Module[{n,symgp,i,goodguys,M2},n=Max[Flatten[M]];
symgp=GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[n]];
M2=Sort[Sort/@M];
goodguys=Select[M2==Sort[Sort/@PermutationReplace[M2,#]]&]@GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[n]];
PermutationGroup[goodguys]]`

Answer (score 3):

`GroupStabilizer` allows you to include an action function `f` via `GroupStabilizer[group, {p1, p2, ...}, f]`! The syntax `GroupStabilizer[group, {p1, p2, ...}, f]` asks for the simultaneous stabilizer of *all* of the points `{p1, p2, ...}`, but here we just want the stabilizer of a single point `blists`, so we'll expect to use `GroupStabilizer[group, {blists}, f]`.

If these are bona-fide sets at both levels (and not lists), we can canonicalize the form of a set by using `Sort[Sort /@ blists]` (sorting each inner list, then the whole list of lists). (You already have this in your solution implicitly, but just to put this here for the general audience; likewise for some of the following!)

So, our action function can be defined as follows. It expects to take in a point (here, `blists`) as first argument, and a group element `g` as a second argument. Luckily, the usual action `PermutationReplace` replaces at every level of the expression, so we can just apply it to the entire `blists` and then canonicalize:

```
f[blists_, g_] := Sort[Sort /@ PermutationReplace[blists, g]]
```

Then

```
matroidAuts[blists_] :=
    GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[Max@Flatten[blists]],
                    {Sort[Sort /@ blists]}, f]
```

should work, but I haven't been able to test it. Let me know if it does!

#### Update: benchmarking

Using

```
RandomM[n_] := Sort[Sort /@ RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, n}]]
m = M[8];
```

your code finishes in about half a second, whereas mine takes about 17 (!). I'm honestly pretty surprised that the built-in function is worse than brute-forcing it—what is the built-in function even doing?!

They seem to give the same (trivial group) answer. I don't know how they'd fare in the nontrivial case yet, but I can't imagine it'd be much different!

I tried speeding up your code by using `Sow` and `Reap`, and (separately) by using `Select`, but only shaved off a tiny bit. `Select` seemed faster by a hair. In general, though, when you're building big lists (which we're not in this benchmark, since the automorphism group is often trivial), `AppendTo` is slow. I'll put my code here in case it's of any use!

```
matroidauts2[M0_] := With[{M = Sort[Sort /@ M0]},
  PermutationGroup @
   Select[GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[Max[Flatten[M]]]], 
    (M == Sort[Sort /@ PermutationReplace[M, #]]) &]]

matroidauts3[M0_] := With[{M = Sort[Sort /@ M0]},
  PermutationGroup @
   First[Last[
     Reap[
       If[M == Sort[Sort /@ PermutationReplace[M, #]], Sow[#]] & /@       
         GroupElements[SymmetricGroup@Max@Flatten[M]];]]]]
```

Comment: For the examples above, your function matroidAuts is a bit faster!